# Conveter array em string e salvar no banco de dados com Codeignater

Tags: php

Tenho um conjunto checkbox para enviar como string para o banco de dados para o mesmo campo separado por virgula, no entanto estou recebendo um retorno para converter em Array de string conforme abaixo:

No controller tenho o seguinte método para tratar as checkbox:

```php
if( isset( $_POST['documento'] ) && is_array( $_POST['documento'] ) ) {
    $documentos = implode( ', ', $_POST['documento'] );
} else {
    $documentos = '';
}
```

Na view, os checkbox:

```html
<div class="customcheck">
      <input type="checkbox" value="RG" name="documento[]">
      <input type="checkbox" value="CPF" name="documento[]">
      
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

testei assim e deu certo:

```
<form action="resposta.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" value="RG" name="documento[]">
    <input type="checkbox" value="CPF" name="documento[]">
    <input type="checkbox" value="certidão" name="documento[]">
    <input type="checkbox" value="titulo" name="documento[]">
    <input type="checkbox" value="CPF" name="documento[]">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

arquivo resposta.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['documento']) && is_array($_POST['documento'])) {
    $documentos = implode(', ', $_POST['documento']);
} else {
    $documentos = '';
}

$username = '****';
$password = '****';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stackoverflow', $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO documentos (documentos) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$documentos]);

    echo "Enviado com sucesso!";

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

banco de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE `documentos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `documentos` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `documentos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: Não modifiquei nada no seu código

Comment: Estou usando o Framework Codeignater para o exemplo e quando você coloca  está estrutura 
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stackoverflow', $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO documentos (documentos) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$documentos]);

    echo "Enviado com sucesso!";

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}  não consigo ver dentro do modelo aplicar no meu exemplo.

Comment: Postei aí em baixo o controller com a função para salvar, conforme tinha te informado segue a estrutura do Codeignater (MODEL, CONTROLLER e VIEW) tenho varios controles e eles estão sendo salvo no banco normalmente apenas não estou conseguindo deixar como string as opção marcadas no checkbox . Retorna uma mensagem dizendo: Message: Cannot unset string offsets depois de ter alterado o código

Comment: no sua resposta acredito que você subscreve a variável $data com uma "string" e depois tenta acessar uma array que não existe $data["se_img"]

Comment: *você sobrescreve

Comment: Entendi, estou atribuindo um valor para  $data = $string_json; e logo depois atribuo  $data["se_img"],  é neste caso que você fala em sobrescrever. Certo, então devo usar outro nome para variável que esta recebendo o array de documento. No seu exemplo salvou considerando você tinha apenas o form com os input checkbox, no meu caso tenho vários inputs

Comment: Observei que no retorno tem a seguinte linha VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', Array, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), observe que manda um array e não a listas de values selecionados